# Почему не работает обращение к переменной в статическом контексте?

Tags: java

Вот код, который не работает:

```
public class Solution
{
public final int A = 5;
public final static int B = 2;
public final static int C = A*B;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
}

public static int getValue()
{
    return C;
}

}
```

а вот который работает:

```
public class Solution
{
public final static int A = 5;
public final static int B = 2;
public final static int C = A*B;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
}

public int getValue()
{
    return C;
}

}
```

Вынесли `static` из функции и поставили его в переменную и всё работает.
Насколько я понимаю, статическая функция может работать только со статическими переменными. Если она по условию возвращает статическую `С`, то получается `С` и функция должны быть статичными. Обьясите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Просто следуйте простому правилу: из статического контекста можно работать только со статическими объектами/методами/классами.

В первом случае, вы определили переменную `A`, к которой нельзя обратиться из статического контекста (модификатор `static` отсутствует), поэтому и возникает ошибка компиляции: значение переменной `C` не может быть вычислено.

Во втором случае всё нормально. Есть 3 статических переменных, к одной из них происходит обращение из нестатического метода - это допустимо. При этом метод можно сделать статическим, как в первом случае.